# How can I power level in Disgaea 2?

Tags: disgaea-2

Ordeals 4 is the standard power leveling map in Disgaea games, but in Disgaea 2 (Dark Hero Days, the PSP version) the enemy formation is 2x4 instead of 3x3, meaning I can't kill them all in one turn. They're too spaced out and no attack (that I know of) has an AoE that hits all of them in one strike.

Is there a better map or some ability that will let me hit everyone on the map in one move? Using two characters to kill them in two attacks is painfully slow, and I don't know of any attack AoE  that will kill the 2x4 formation.

Powerleveling on this map takes too long so I gave up, but I wonder if there is a better way. Magichange is an option but I don't know of any magichange weapon attacks that have this range either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no skill that has an area of effect large enough to cover all 8 squares of the 2x4 configuration of enemies in the Cave of Ordeals 4.  It will take you a minimum of two characters to clear CoO4.

Here are some skills with very large area of effect:

- Winged Slayer (Sword): (3x3)
- Dimension Slash (Sword): (1x5)
- Big Bang (Fist): (3x3)
- Magic (Any): Up to 3x3

CoO4 is still the best level to gain levels fast.  The official Disgaea 2 Strategy guide by Doublejump books has a very long procedure for power leveling.  Here are the high points:

- Make some level 1283 or higher Nekomatas by combining, capturing them, and repeating.
- Unlock the ability to create Carmillas.
- In the Dark World 5-2, kill the two Carmillas closest to the base, and the Geo Clone Symbol.  Wait turns for the Level 1300 Carmilla to get to L2197.  Kill 2 Level Up Geo Symbols, and wait 1 more turn.  Attack the Carmilla to weaken her; hold her up during Round ends to avoid her gaining any more levels. Send your L1283 Nekomata back into the base panel and then throw in the Carmilla to capture her.
- Repeat the above step as necessary to get to Level 9999 Carmillas.
- Capture as many of the Level 9999 Carmillas as you want, and reincarnate them into Space Knights (boost your INT with all your bonus points).
- Max out an Armsmaster Specialist at 1900.  Same for Manager (300), Mentor (300), Broker (300) and Professional (100).  Also make a Firefighter, Aeronaut or Cryophile at 100 - whichever matches your Skull.  Also make a maxxed out Lovers for both Magicians and Magic Knights.
- Also make 10 Level 19998 Nerds.  (The guide notes that **this** is the tedious step.)
- Make a Skull in your favorite element (fire in this example).  Equip the Skull with your best staff. Everything else should increase his SP. Put all of the Specialists above on his equipment.
- Teach you Skull Tera-fire, and then cast Tera-fire on an enemy immune to fire until Tera-fire is at level 52.  This is best done on an Attack+X panel.
- Reincarnate the Skull into a Genius Space Knight.  Switch out the Lover on the newly-minted Space Knight's equipment.
- Pass all Stronger Enemy bills in the Senate.
- Spend a couple of hours soloing the new Space Knight in *Cave of Ordeals 4* to reach Level 9999.

(Seriously, that's the short version.)

At the final step, and every other step where non-monsters need to level up, CoO4 is the place to go.

Comment: I can kill them in one hit (depending on level) but taking two turns makes it go from mindless grinding into something that takes a lot of time. Is there nothing that takes them out in one move?

Comment: I'm kinda thinking that if you can't kill them in one move, your attacker isn't aren't at a high level.  I'm assuming that you're watching your elements, and buffing your attacker as needed...\

Comment: It's an AoE problem, not a strength problem, which is why I'm asking. I can kill any one of them in one shot, but I don't have any moves that can hit all 8 (in a 2x4 formation) in one strike

Comment: @benBrocka - I've updated my answer based on your clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be a bit late to this party, but if anyone is still wondering how to one hit Cave of Ordeals 4 map. Here is a method.

**Note:** Only works for Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days

You will need:

- Zetta
- Magi-change-2 unlocked on Zetta (randomly encounter Mao in Item World and choosing Zetta)
- Another monster to use for magi-change
- A humanoid character

So what you do is:

1. Magi-change your chosen monster character with you chosen humanoid character
2. Then Magi-change 2 with Zetta
3. Use Zetta Beeeam which has a large enough AoE to hit all monsters

This method also has the added benefit of leveling 3 characters (Zetta, your chosen humanoid and your chosen monster).

Answer (score 0):

Have another character throw the monsters. One will be in front of a 2x3 row, and another will be thrown on top of another monster (for double level). So row 1 will have 3 monsters (one with double level), row 2 will have 3, and row 3 (closes to panel) will have 1 thrown monster. Then hit with Winged slayer/big bang.